# Question describing the span of 3 vectors using a single equation of a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

T-F: 
The linear span of the vectors $(4,0,0,1)$, $(0,2,0,-1)$, and $(4,3,2,1)$ is the 3-plane 
$x_1 - 2x_2 + 3x_3 -4x_4 = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

I can substitute each vector into the equation and verify that each of the vectors lives on the plane, but I wonder if there is a matrix approach to this.

If I put the four vectors into a matrix, then the question is asking if the column space of the matrix is the plane. The equation of the plane gives a rank one matrix; the nullspace of that matrix has the right dimension (3), but that approach is more of a guess than a real understanding.

Comment: Is your question "How do I find a set of equations describing the span of an arbitrary set of vectors using matrices?" or is it "How do I use matrices to verify that this particular statement is true?"

Comment: Nice question. 
"How do I find a set of equations describing the span of an arbitrary set of vectors using matrices?" is closer to what I want to understand. The true-false questions 20-23 here http://www.math.washington.edu/~smith/Teaching/308/2013-Spring-Midterm-Answers.pdf are what I would like to be able to do.

Comment: Those questions seem to be much simpler than the one you are asking.  Note that determining whether a subset qualifies as a (vector) subspace does not require that you find a basis for that subspace.

Comment: The question I asked is #18 from the link. The hard part about the other questions for me is determining the dimensionality of the subspace.

Comment: You might want to post another question for 20-23. The quick explanation, though, is that a subspace of $n$-dimensional space determined by $k$ non-redundant equations is $n-k$-dimensional. You could approach this with matrices and row-reduction, if you prefer a procedural approach.

Comment: As for this question: once you know that this space definitely contains these three vectors and that this space does not contain all of $\mathbb{R}^4$, it is enough to show that these three vectors are linearly independent (and thus form a basis of the subspace), which can be done by row reducing the matrix of column vectors.

Comment: Thanks @Omno, both of those comments are helpful. I think I need a little more explanation for questions 20-23, so I will make another post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Consider the orthogonal complement. The orthogonal complement of the orthogonal complement is the same space in finite dimension.

Let the matrix $M$ have each row being the vectors you want to find the linear span of. Then $Mv=0$ whenever $v$ is orthogonal. You want to find a basis $v_{i}$ of the null space of $M$, which is easily done using reduced row echolon. Then let $N$ be the matrix where each row is $v_{i}$. Then $Nu=0$ if and only if $u$ is the span of the original vector. Now you might end up with more than 1 equation, but that's to be expected. After all, in your case, you have a 4-dimensional space and look for a 3-dimensional subspace, so the number of equation needed is 4-3=1.

Comment: It worked; the basis of the nullspace of M is exactly the vector normal to the plane. Thank you.